# Python - Can't get received time of an outlook file

Tags: python, tkinter, outlook

I have an outlook file saved locally. I am using **filedialog.askopenfile** to ask the user to direct the script to the file, this works fine.

However when I then try to check the receive date of the file I am getting the following error:

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', "We can't open 'Desktop/emails/email.msg'. It's possible the file is already open, or you don't have permission to open it.\n\nTo check your permissions, right-click the file folder, then click Properties.", None, 0, -2147287038), None)

I think the issue is that I am opening the file when I ask the User to point to the file and then trying to open it again with msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(dir1) but I don't know how to resolve this.

**My Code**

```
from tkinter import *
  
# import filedialog module
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk

def your_script(dir1):
    
    
    ## Import Libraries
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from pandas import DataFrame
    import win32com.client as client
    import pathlib
    import win32com.client
    import datetime
    from datetime import datetime
    from time import strftime
    
    ######################################################################################################################
    ######################################################################################################################
    

    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNamespace('MAPI')
    # Open email
    msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(dir1)
    
    #Get email receive date
    dt = msg.ReceivedTime
    dt = datetime.strptime('2021-01-16', '%Y-%m-%d')
    dt = dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
    dt

# Ask User to point to file
dir1 =  filedialog.askopenfile(mode="r", initialdir="/", title="select the first file",
                                       filetypes=(("Last quarters email", "*.msg"), ("all files", "*.*")))

your_script(dir1)
```

Comment: `filedialog.askopenfile` opens the file. Try using `filedialog.askopenfilename` instead

Answer (score 0):

As [@TheLizzard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11106801/thelizzard) [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69093943/python-cant-get-received-time-of-an-outlook-file#comment122116758_69093943), you are passing a fileobject to your function, but are expecting a path.

This returns the fileobject

```py
filedialog.askopenfile()
```

Whereas this returns the path to the file

```py
filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

your

```py
outlock.OpenSharedItem(dir1)
```

wants a filepath not a fileobject

Comment: I think that `OpenSharedItem` is able to accept file like objects. Look at the error *""We can't open 'Desktop/emails/email.msg' ..."*, it is able to get the file path from the file like object. I think that the problem is that `filedialog.askopenfile()` actually opens the file and as the error message states *"It's possible the file is already open"*

Comment: @TheLizzard thank you for your comments. But when I change the script to filedialog.askopenfilename() I still get the same error.

Comment: instead of using `msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(dir1)`, use `msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(dir1.name)`

Answer (score 0):

The error is `STG_E_FILENOTFOUND`, whcih means there is no file with the given name. You must pass a string with the fully qualified file name, not an object.

Comment: thank you for the comment however I'm not sure how to do this. I have tried converting the object to a string but it still won't work

Comment: @PythonBeginner Try passing in the full path to the file. I think that [`os.path.asbpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) will be useful

Comment: @TheLizzard I'm not sure I understand how to do so